# How do I write a regex that either substitutes OR just adds new substring at the begging of a string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that can either look like `"string"` (first case) or `[word]string[word]` (second case).

My goal is to change it to be `[new_word]string[new_word]`.

If I use `my_string = re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]', [new_word], my_string)` it only works for the first case.

Can I modify the regex to work for both cases or should I use `if` statement instead?

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'^(?:\[[^]]*])?(.*?)(?:\[[^]]*])?$', r'[new_word]\1[new_word]', s)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TL9mB2/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex alternation (`|`) to achieve this:

```
my_string = re.sub(r'(?:\[[^\]]*\]|")', '[new_word]', my_string)
```

Explanation:

```
(?:                    # Beginning of alternating group
    \[[^\]]*\]         # Matches [word]
    |                  # OR
    "                  # Matches literal double quote
)
```

[Live Demo](http://codepad.org/sq4eQluP)